# Read specified data from text file and plot it using Matlab

Tags: matlab, text

I have a text file containing following data:

```
2n10
B127 mg/dL  01:45 pm 3 of January
E83 mg/dL  10:03 am 3 of January
H97 mg/dL  11:05 pm 2 of January
K80 mg/dL  06:00 am 3 of January
P118 mg/dL  08:15 am 3 of January
S97
S80
S118
S81
S87
S85
S89
S82
S83
S127
a
```

And I want to read some (specified) data from this text file and then plot it.
The data that I want to read and plot is:

```
S97
S80
S118
S81
S87
S85
S89
S82
S83
S127
```

How can I do that ?

Hints:

- First part of file:

  ```
  2n10
  B127 mg/dL  01:45 pm 3 of January
  E83 mg/dL  10:03 am 3 of January
  H97 mg/dL  11:05 pm 2 of January
  K80 mg/dL  06:00 am 3 of January
  P118 mg/dL  08:15 am 3 of January
  ```

  Always consists of six rows, so the first line that I actually want to read and plot starts from the seventh row.
- Second part of file (which I want to read and plot) may contain an arbitrary number of rows, but every row starts with character `S` and the end of file is always marked by character `a`.

Please help me ^_^

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Those data to be neglected always have more than one word in those rows?

Comment: And the valid rows (that are to be considered for plot) are always single string/word?

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be this one:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');

tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    parts = textscan(tline, 'S%d');
    if numel(parts{1}) > 0
        disp(['S' num2str(parts{1}) ])
    end
    tline = fgets(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

Basically, it opens the file and searches for lines with the format:

> S< number >

For each one of these lines, it scans the number and prints the string without the *newline*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir Antonio L ^_^

Please , when I run your excellent program I get these Data :

S97
S80
S118
S81
S87
S85
S89
S82
S83
S127

The variable of these data are tline or parts ?

How can I remove the the char ( S ) and then plot it ? 

Regards ...

Comment: _parts{1}_ contains the number itself. If you want to print the numbers without the _S_, just delete the _'S'_ in the call to _disp_. Regards.

Comment: Thanks Sir Antonio ^_^